# Storing permutation matrix in a vector form

Tags: matrices, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, permutation-matrices

I've seen that permutation matrix doesn't have to be stored in a matrix form, but in a vector form, where each entry corresponds to column where 1 is located. But then how do we apply permutation on matrix given such a vector (using matlab)?

Comment: `A(:,p)` or `A(p,:)` depending on column or row permutations

Comment: @user251257Is there a way to store a product of permutation matrices, as opposed to store each permutation matrix as a vector?

Comment: product of permutations is a permutation again.